# jquery slideDown/slideUp with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown

how can I use this script for multiple Divs?

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slidedown_head').toggle(function(){
        $('.slidedown_body').slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $('.slidedown_body').slideUp();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slidedown_head">
    Blub
</div>
<div class="slidedown_body" style="display:none">
    <p>bla</p>
    <p>blablub</p>
</div>
<div class="slidedown_head">
    Blub
</div>
<div class="slidedown_body" style="display:none">
    <p>bla</p>
    <p>blablub</p>
</div>
```

If i click on "Blub" both divs slide down.
I don't want to add for every Div an individual ID and an individual Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to grab the correct body element, and [`slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) like this:

```
$('.slidedown_head').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.slidedown_body').slideToggle();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwS/)

Answer (score 0):

I've added the CSS code to make it look nicer

```css
.slidedown_body{
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $panel = $('.slidedown_head'); 
$panel.click(function() {
   $(this).next('.slidedown_body').slideToggle("fast",function() {
  $('.slidedown_body').animate({width: '120px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow"); return true;});
});
});
```

```
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;   
  border: 2px solid;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #BDBDBD;
}
```